# asyncronous try catch phrase not working discord.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord, discord.js, try-catch

I am trying to implement a discord chatbot into my own bot, isn't good at handling some characters and stuff like the quotes of discord (type > and space to know that I mean). It often crashes becauses it thinks the message is empty. I wanted to use a try catch phrase so it won't crash. The complete function is asyncronous and I think that's why it isn't working how I want it to do. It still crashes without logging the thrown error.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
        if(message.channel.id === "1006483461747527772" && !message.author.bot){
            if(containsLetters(message.content)) {
                //console.log(message.content.length)
                try{
                    let reply = await chat.chat(message.content)
                    client.channels.cache.get("1006483461747527772").send(reply)
                } catch(err){
                    client.channels.cache.get("1006483461747527772").send(err)
                }  
                
            }
        } 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robotgozoooom's answer is correct that to send an error message to Discord you need to use `error.message`, but there's another problem: when Discord throws the `Cannot send empty message` error it is in an async function, so the try/catch doesn't actually catch the error. You need to add a `.catch()` function to the end of your async function instead of using a try/catch at all:

```
if (containsLetters(message.content)) {
    let reply = await chat.chat(message.content);
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get("1006483461747527772");
    channel.send(reply).catch((err) => channel.send(err.message));
}
```

Comment: `await channel.send(reply);` should work just fine though

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but yes, because we don't need the return value from that function, and we don't need to wait for it to finish, it doesn't matter if you have `await channel.send(reply).catch` or just `channel.send(reply).catch`

Comment: No, I mean that there's no reason to use `.catch()` in particular. `try { await channel.send(reply); } catch(err) { … }` works just as well, and it seems the OP would prefer `try`/`catch`

Comment: That's actually what I had thought too, but I just tested it out before posting and the `catch` will catch the error (so you can log it to console), but it won't stop the bot from crashing and going offline, which then makes you unable to send a message with the error

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you are running into here is that the object `err` is not a String. Try appending `.message` to `err` so then it reads `err.message`. If that doesn't work (or even if it does), I would recommend against sending the error message in discord since that presents more variables to interfere with debugging (what if something was wrong with the client object or with the channel id string?). Instead, I normally use `console.error(err)`. Hope this helps!